# Ignore errors in UFT without generating a warning

Tags: hp-uft

On certain pages in my tests I have are-you-sure-popups that my or may not show up.
I solve this obvious problem using

```
On Error Resume Next
[Click OK]
```

This works fine but for all the popups that have actually not been present but it generates a warning which does look unnecessarily alarming. Is there any way to suppress these warning in UFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
On Error Resume Next
Reporter.Filter = rfDisableAll
Dialog("TITLE").Button("LABEL").Click
Reporter.Filter = rfEnableAll
On Error GoTo 0
```

This is the Hacky Way.

For a very pure implementation you should be deterministic: always be in control, always know, what will happen and use the Exist Property on the Object if it's optional.

For Random Events the UFT Solution is Recovery Scenarios - but I did not see many implementations for it.